# Order by output of a class method rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scope

I'm trying to output a JSON response ordered by a particular class method on a model. I know I can order by actual attributes, but how to I order by sending in a block. To wit:

```
class Baker
  has_many :meals

  def this_week_cookies
    self.meals.this_week.sum(:cookies_baked)
  end
end
```

I want to call something like

> Baker.order{|baker| baker.this_week_cookies}

to output a leaderboard in a view, but I know that won't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `order` method is writing a SQL query so it can't use a custom method like that. You would need to use ruby to do what you want.

`Baker.all.sort_by(&:this_week_cookies)`